# Dynamically parsing XML in Databricks

Tags: xml, pyspark, xml-parsing, databricks

a table in my database contains a column with large XML string data. The issue is that I want to dynamically pass a string to parse the XML.

This example shows more or less what kind of result I would like to achieve:

[image]

```
SELECT
  from_xml(
    '<fruits><fruit>banana</fruit><fruit>apple</fruit></fruits>',
    schema_of_xml(
      '<fruits><fruit>banana</fruit><fruit>apple</fruit></fruits>'
    )
  );
```

However, the function `schema_of_xml` only accepts a static value.

I decided to try to solve it using pyspark, below are the examples that works for individual rows:

[image]
and
[image]

There was also an attempt to write a UDF to use it with the "map" function. However, I've encountered some issues with utilizing RDDs:
[image]